# Match similar column values in different rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with an ID column (String) and I need to be able to find IDs that are *similar* between different rows.  What is the SQL that will allow me to flag a row as similar?  Note: There can be one-to-many rows like shown below (i.e. 12345, 12345RED, etc.)

Update: The IDs are "similar" in that there is typically leading numerical values followed by no space then alpha characters OR space " ", hyphen "-", or forward slash "/" then followed by alpha characters. ####[a-zA-z], #### [a-zA-Z], ####-[a-zA-z}, or ####/[a-zA-z].  (I'm not sure how to indicate 1-to-many numeric characters).

| ID | Similar |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Yes |
| 12345RED (Could also be 12345-RED, 12345/RED, or 12345 RED) | Yes |
| 12345BLU (Could also be 12345-BLU, 12345/BLU, or 12345 BLU) | Yes |
| 12345GRN (Could also be 12345-GRN, 12345/GRN, or 12345 GRN) | Yes |
| 12345BLK (Could also be 12345-BLK, 12345/BLK, or 12345 BLK) | Yes |
| 123456 | No |
| 123457 | No |

Comment: What does "similar" mean to you? That the initial numeric characters are an exact match, but anything from the first non-numeric character onwards can be anything? And how are you specifying which row the others are being compared against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "similar" means "have the same leading numerals"...

First, extract the numerals, such as with a regular expression. Then, count how many other ros have the same leading numerals, using a window function.

```
WITH
  extract_numerals AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(id, r'^\d+') AS leading_numerals
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY leading_numerals) - 1   AS similar_rows
FROM
  extract_numerals
ORDER BY
  leading_numerals
```

Any row where the count is zero (after having deducted one from the window function) has no "similar" rows.

Comment: I realized the actual question was the wrong approach and ended up just needing your idea around the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` and running from there.

Comment: @user2715877 in regex `*` means "0 or more" and `+` means "1 or more"